# Python - Pandas, How to aggregate by months inside a date interval efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, etl

I am trying to compute aggregation metrics with pandas of a dataset with a start and finish date of a month interval, i need to do this efficiently because my dataset can have millions of rows.
My dataset is like this

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

df = pd.DataFrame([["2020-01-01", "2020-05-01", 200],
                   ["2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", 100],
                   ["2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", 350],
                   ["2020-02-01", "2020-05-01", 500]], columns=["start", "end", "value"])

df["start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start"])
df["end"] = pd.to_datetime(df["end"])
```

[image]

And i want to have something like this:

[image]

I've tried two approaches, making a month timerange with the start and end dates and exploding them, then grouping by month:

```
df["months"] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x["start"], x["end"], freq="MS"), axis=1)
df_explode = df.explode("months")
df_explode.groupby("months")["value"].agg(["mean", "sum", "std"])
```

The other one is iterating month by month, checking what month rows contain this month, then aggregating them:

```
rows = []
for m in pd.date_range(df.start.min(), df.end.max(), freq="MS"):
    rows.append(df[(df.start <= m) & (m <= df.end)]["value"].agg(["mean", "sum", "std"]))
pd.DataFrame(rows, index=pd.date_range(df.start.min(), df.end.max(), freq="MS"))
```

The first approach works faster with smaller datasets, the second one is best with bigger datasets, but I'd want to know if there is a better approach for doing this better and faster.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to your second approach, but vectorized.  It assumes your start and end dates are month starts.

```
month_starts = pd.date_range(df.start.min(), df.end.max(), freq="MS")[:-1].to_numpy()
contained = np.logical_and(
    np.greater_equal.outer(month_starts, df["start"].to_numpy()),
    np.less.outer(month_starts, df["end"].to_numpy()),
)
masked = np.where(contained, np.broadcast_to(df[["value"]].transpose(),contained.shape), np.nan)
pd.DataFrame(masked, index=month_starts).agg(["mean", "sum", "std"], axis=1)
```